# Creating an ordered list out of a python list item

Tags: python, html, jinja2

Have a list called `whatever` that I want to itemize in Jinja:

```
<ol>
{% for item in whatever %}
<tr>
    <td>
       <li> {{ item }}</li>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

However, when I implement this in this way, I get unordered list output rather than sequential numbers, i.e.

- item 1
- item 2
- etc.

rather than

1. item 1
2. item 2
3. etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually a problem with your html (and not python / jinja). It you remove the `tr`/`td` tags it will be ok.

Update: If you insist on using the table tags, drop the `ol`/`li` tags, and use the `loop` object that is implicitly defined in the jinja `for` loop. That is,

```
<td>{{loop.index}}. {{item}}</td>
```

will give you enumerated item.